# Insert a set of hashmaps into cache

Tags: java, caching, dictionary

How to insert a set of hashmaps into cache?

After executing the below code I got Below Exception.

```
net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheException: Could not find class: 'ri.cache.BasicCacheFactory'
at net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheManager.getCacheFactory(CacheManager.java:46)
at InsertIntoCACHE.main(InsertIntoCACHE.java:17)
```

I want insert a hashmap as value with String as Key.Any help is hugely appreciated

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;
import net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache;
import net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheException;
import net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheFactory;
import net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheManager;

public class InsertIntoCACHE {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Cache cache;

       try {
          CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance().getCacheFactory();
          cache = cacheFactory.createCache(Collections.emptyMap());
          String key="21";      
          byte[] value=("Twenty One").getBytes();    
          cache.put(key, value);
          value = (byte[]) cache.get(key);
          System.out.println(value);
      } catch (CacheException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [imcache](http://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache). You can construct a cache as follows,

```
Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.concurrentHeapCache().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

JSR107 is not a cache, but an API. You need a concrete cache product that provides an implementation for it. I expect that all major cache products will provide it. Since JSR107 is finalized a few months ago, it may take some time to appear. In general take a look on caching products like, EHCache, Infinispan, Hazelcast, imcache and cache2k and decide for one to use.